# Entity Framework. SQL Group By to EF Group By

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, datetime, group-by

I am trying to define a standard way to group by year, by month, by day, by hour, etc ...

By reading some SQL documentation it seems the most efficient way would be to use:

```
GROUP BY dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, CreatedDate), 0)
```

Note the "month", "year", ...

I then tried to replicate this using:

```
.GroupBy(x => SqlFunctions.DateAdd("month", SqlFunctions.DateDiff("month", 0, x.Created), 0))

.GroupBy(x => EntityFunctions.AddMonths(EntityFunctions.DiffMonths(0, x.Created)))
```

However, both expression failed to compile ...

And I am not sure if this is the way to do it?

How can I correctly replicate that SQL code line in EF?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't understand Why would you want to use the standard sql to do that any way, however this can be done easily using LINQ and it would be more *standard*, grouping by an anonymous type for example like this:

```
.GroupBy( x => new 
               {
                  month = x.CreatedDate.Month,
                  year = x.CreatedDate.Year,
                  ...
               });
```

Comment: Yes, I have that working. But if I am not mistaken using something as I posted has better performance, not? I was reading the following: http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2007/09/10/group-by-month-sql.aspx ...

Comment: This is way I was trying to find a way to replicate that SQL code using EntityFunctions ... And at the same time create a standard way to group by years, by months, by days, by hours, ... I would just need to change AddYears to AddMonths, to ...

Comment: It does not have any performance benefit.  The post you linked to just states that it makes it easier to work with in Sql.  I don't see there being that much of a benefit doing it that way with Entity Framework.  .NET does not have the same limitations as Sql.

Comment: @Shapper Why try and prematurely optimize? If you find performance problems that is when you need to try and improve the performance.

Comment: But how would you group by month? I have the following:

posts.Where(x => x.CreatedDate >= startDate && x.CreatedDate <= endDate)
.GroupBy(x => new { Year = x.Created.Year, Month = x.Created.Month })
.Select(x => new { Key = new DateTime(x.Key.Year, x.Key.Month, 0), Value = x.Count() });

The part "new DateTime" is not supporter in EF.

Comment: So don't use `new DateTime` in your query.  Do the count, get the month and the year.  Bring all the data into memory, then make the DateTime